# Google Apps Script - Chart Service: How to format numbers and dates

Tags: google-apps-script, pygooglechart

I´ve managed to create a datatable and a simple chart using data from a google spreadsheet. Here is the code:

```
 function doGet() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x9g2N5gFCAeU6DkS-BYiB6womhsNfT3kPH2L22ZI3iM/edit#gid=973420299");
   var sheetDados = ss.getSheetByName("Receita e Investimento");
   var dataTableValeus = sheetDados.getRange(16, 1, 31, 3).getValues();



   var data = Charts.newDataTable()
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, "Data")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Cost")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Revenue");

   for(var linha = 0, len = dataTableValeus.length; linha < len; linha++){
     if (dataTableValeus[linha][0] != ""){
       data.addRow(dataTableValeus[linha]);
     }
   }

   data.build();

   var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
       .setDataTable(data)
       .setRange(0, 40)
       .setTitle("Revenue and Cost")
       .build();

   var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Chart");
   uiApp.add(chart);
   return uiApp;
 }
```

And here is the end product: [Simple Chart](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwc8RyFPJpRrqa23zdw9KorpDq6Rc1LCXS9Re3bOYON1tk8YRQ/exec)

My problem is changing the format of the date and number on the Axis.

On the X-Axis it reads now "12 de nov de 2015". I want to change it to 12/nov/2015

and on the Y-Axis it reads now "7.500", "15.000"... I want change it to "R$ 7.500", "R$ 15.500".

How can I format this?!

here is the link for the [spreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x9g2N5gFCAeU6DkS-BYiB6womhsNfT3kPH2L22ZI3iM/edit#gid=973420299)

Comment: it seems to be dependant on your locale settings... when I deploy it I get [this result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/211279/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202015-12-29%20%C3%A0%2000.08.40.png)

Comment: I found the answer by my own.. But I thought it would be nice to share with the community, since I haven´t seen many question on this topic...

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution to this short after I´ve posted the question. Here is the answer.

The method `Charts.setOption(option, value)` enables a fair deal of customization to your chart.

Here is the [description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/area-chart-builder#setOption(String,Object)) of the method and here is a descriptions of the [parameters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) it accepts.

My final code looks like this:

```
 function doGet() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x9g2N5gFCAeU6DkS-BYiB6womhsNfT3kPH2L22ZI3iM/edit#gid=973420299");
   var sheetDados = ss.getSheetByName("Receita e Investimento");
   var dataTableValeus = sheetDados.getRange(16, 1, 31, 3).getValues();



   var data = Charts.newDataTable()
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, "Data")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Cost")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Revenue");

   for(var linha = 0, len = dataTableValeus.length; linha < len; linha++){
     if (dataTableValeus[linha][0] != ""){
       data.addRow(dataTableValeus[linha]);
     }
   }

   data.build();


   var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
       .setDataTable(data)
       .setTitle("Revenue and Cost")
       .setOption("vAxis.format", "currency")
       .setOption("hAxis.format", "d/MMM/y")
       .setOption("legend.position", "top")
       .setDimensions(600, 300)
       .build();

   var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Chart");
   uiApp.add(chart);
   return uiApp;
 }
```